# How to pass value from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I Have a question.

I need to pass a value in `C# and MVC3` to a controller but I don't know how.

The code in my view is :

```
@html.textbox("Name"); 
<input value="Envoyer" type="submit">
```

How can I get the value of `name` to my controller, please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is another way.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index() {

    string name = Request["name"];
}
```

Comment: Can I get this from @html.textbox("Name"); ? Really ?

Comment: @steffi here, you will see a sample of mine : http://forums.asp.net/t/1669915.aspx/1?Simple+search+page

Comment: @steffi also, you do not need semi-colon after @Html.TextBox("Name") as you have written on the comment

Answer (score 6):

Wrap it in a form and have a submit button of some sort to call your Action Method.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("MethodName", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {%>
     <% Html.Textbox("Name") %> 
     <input value="Envoyer" type="submit" />
<% } %>



[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MethodName(FormCollection col)
{
    string name = col["Name"];
}
```

Comment: isn't this wrong? you have used web form view engine and razor together above.

Comment: also, this **@html.textbox("Name");** syntactically wrong. it should have been **@Html.TextBox("Name")**

Comment: that's all in perfect shape now except the ***ActionMethod*** thing on your c# code. shouldn't that be something else? like ***ActionResult***? I just noticed that too

Comment: <input value="Envoyer" type="submit"> doesn't have the closing tag. :)

Answer (score 3):

<strike><%= Model %></strike>

In MVC 3, you see the <dynamic> set as model by default in your view. Just pass a string as object to the view (return View((object)"Name");) from your controller.

[Also see this for a more complex example.](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/07/27/asp-net-mvc-3-new-viewmodel-is-dynamic-viewdata.aspx)

[Edit]

I have got to start reading better :)

Ok, here we go.

The easyest way to do this, is via a <form>. Any input element is posted to your controller where the 'name' attribute will be the variable name (parameter).

Example:

```
<form action="/Contact/SendMessage" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Your e-mail adres:</th>
            <td class="inputCell">
                <input id="txtEmail" name="Email" type="text" value="<%= Model %>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <textarea name="Message" rows="10" style="width: 450px;"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" style="text-align: right;"><input type="submit" id="SendButton" value="Send Message" /></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

On the controller, you can have your function like:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public RedirectResult SendMessage(String Email, String Message)
{
}
```

Comment: Seems good. Why do you use HTML and not <asp: .../> or <% %> ?

Comment: You don't typically use server tags in MVC.

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap it in a form, as has already been offered:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.Textbox("Name")

    <input value="Envoyer" type="submit">
}
```

And then in your controller action simply declare a parameter with the name `Name` (assuming this is happening in a view called `Index`):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string Name)
{
    // do whatever with Name
}
```

Using the `FormCollection` as has been said is also a perfectly valid option, but this is even easier and a little cleaner, in my opinion.