# Pass parameter not in model class to stored procedure in controller ASP.NET Core 3 MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I am creating a ticketing page and want the user to add  tickets to each student. Adding tickets is done in the database by the stored procedure which takes parameters that are in the model class and database table like Name, Age, and the Number which is not in the database and the model. The problem is passing the Number parameter which is not in the database table and not in the model class since the system will create tickets according to the Number parameter.

Model class:

```
public class Ticket
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 ID { get; set; }
    public Sring Name { get; set; }
    public  int Age { get; set; }
    public Sring Address { get; set; }
   
    [BindProperty]
    public int Number{ get; set; }
}
```

Please note that I have added the number as `Bindproperty` as this solution:[Passing data from view to controller asp.net core razor pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585081/how-to-pass-value-from-view-to-controller)

Create function which should take the number from the user in the controller

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Name,Age,Address,Number")] Ticket ticket)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var Number = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@Number",
                SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = ticket.Number
            }; 

            var Name = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@Name",
                SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = ticket.Name
            };

            var Age = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@Age",
                SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = ticket.Age
            };

            _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("usp_InsertTickets  @Number,@Name,@Age", Number, Name,Age);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        return View(ticket);
    }
```

The view is:

```
<h4>Ticket</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Number" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Number" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Number" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Age" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Age" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Age" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertTickets]
    @Number int,
    @Name nvarchar(50),
    @Age int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NONumber ON;

    DECLARE @index int;
    SET @index = 0;

    WHILE @index < @Number
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[ut_Ticketing] ([Age], [Name])
        VALUES (@Age, @Name)

        SET @index = @index + 1;
    END

    RETURN 0
END
```

I have followed this solution also:  How to pass value from view to controller[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585081/how-to-pass-value-from-view-to-controller)

Comment: What is the current problem ? Send number from view to controller seems working .

Comment: The problem when adding Number since it's not in the database table. The error statement is as follows: SqlException: Invalid column name 'Number'.  Applying existing migrations for ApplicationDbContext may resolve this issue
There are migrations for ApplicationDbContext that have not been applied to the database

Comment: If Ticket is a data model, you'll need to add the `[NotMapped]` attribute to that field, otherwise Entity Framework thinks it's part of the table definition.